# Storyboard inside a user control is not working

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, user-controls

I am developing a Windows 8 Store App. I have created the following user control:

`<UserControl
    x:Class="RTV_W8.AnimatedImage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RTV_W8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- Animates the rectangle's opacity. -->
        <Storyboard x:Name="ContainerGridStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:5"
            AutoReverse="False">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="PictureImage"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>`

with the following cs file (only partially displayed here)

```
        public AnimatedImage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += AnimatedImage_Loaded;
        this.PictureImage.Loaded += PictureImage_Loaded;
    }

    void AnimatedImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContainerGridStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

my problem is the storyboard is not launching when the image is loaded. This user control is used inside another usercontrol. I have tried multiple variants trying to make the animation to work, none of them worked. I want the user control to animate it's opacity into view, instead of just pooping up. Although i can see via breakpoints that the ContainerGridStoryboard.Begin(); is executed nothing happens on screen

EDIT: In another usercontrol witch is later used in a datatemplate, if i apply the storyboard on the main grid it works, the usercontrol gets animated. But if i apply it on the second grid (contained in the main grid) or any other element, the animation does not work. That is why i created animatedimage in the first place.

Comment: One thing might be in the storyboard you maybe need to create a binding...

Comment: i have set the dependency property (animatedImage has a Source property) and the binding correctly. I can see the images (binding is correct). But the images just pop up. The storyboard (witch should animate the grid and image) is not working.

Comment: try with a trigger...

Comment: I am working in a metro app for Windows 8. triggers are available for wpf but not for metro apps

Comment: i actually have triggers in Windows 8 apps. i have tried <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded" >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"
            AutoReverse="False">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers> but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved the problem. So my usercontrol was inside a couple of grids, inside another usercontrol, inside a datatemplate inside a gridview. The problem was that the main grid witch contained the animatedimage was set with CacheMode="BitmapCache". When i removed that property the images faded in.

Answer (score 0):

When I set the image's source, and embed the UserControl into a page, the image fades in as expected.

Comment: i will test this today

Comment: i have tested the control in a blank page and it works as expected. but if i put the control inside another control, inside a datatemplate, inside a gridview the animation will not fire. The image just pops up

Comment: now i have tried the usercontrol inside a grid, inside a datatemplate, inside a gridview and the animation still does not fire

Comment: ok, i have just tried to put the usercontrol directly inside the datatemplate (the datatemplate contains only the animatedimage usercontrol), inside a gridview and the animation works. This is very strange. I need the datatemplate to be more than just the animatedimage. But when i put the animatedimage inside a grid the animation stops working